# Полноэкранный режим в android < api 19, как скрыть панель навигации?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Задался вопросом как сделать приложение на весь экран.

Для **API 19** и выше работает все идеально с этим кодом.

Для скрытия шапки использую этот код (если знаете другой способ, то подскажите для расширения знаний).

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Далее для скрытия *Navigation Bar* использую этот код:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19)
{
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
         View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION 
       | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
}
```

Загвоздка в том, что для **API 19** и выше панель навигаций(кнопки) при нажатии на экран в пустое место не появляются, только если проводить в область, где они находятся.

Для **API 18** и ниже пытался использовать это:

```
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Но при нажатии в любую область экрана кнопки появляются и больше не пропадают, при это ужимая элементы на экране. Как это обойти?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

До **Android 4.4 (API 19**) нет полноценного полноэкранного режима.
С **Android 4.0 (API 14)** были добавлены два флага к уже существующему `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN`:

- `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE` (затемняет иконки на *Navigation bar* и заменяет их на точки)
- `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION` (говрит системе скрыть *Navigation bar*)

**ВАЖНО:** Даже после применения вышеуказанных флагов *Navigation bar* появится как только пользователь нажмет на любую часть экрана.

> Но при нажатии в любую область экрана кнопки появляются и больше не
>   пропадают, при это ужимая элементы на экране. Как это обойти?

Чтобы при появлении *Navigation bar* не ужимался ваш *layout* необходимо использовать флаги:

- `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE` (который указывает, что *layout* будет жестко фиксированным и независим от того скрыты какие-либо элементы или нет). Так же этот флаг не работает на устройствах с **Ice Cream Sandwich**, так как он появился только в **API 16**.
- `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN` (который указывает, что *layout* будет во весь экран без *Navigation bar*)

А для скрытия их обратно достаточно добавить `Handler` в переопределенные методы `public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)` и `protected void onResume()`.

```
@Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        executeDelayed();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        executeDelayed();
    }


    private void executeDelayed() {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // выполнится спустя 500ms
                // метод, в котором устанавливаются соответствующие флаги
                hideSystemUI();
            }
        }, 500);
    }
```

В **API 19** появился `Immersive` мод, который дает возможность получить полноценный полноэкранный режим. Более подробно об этом режиме отвечали [здесь](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html).

> Загвоздка в том, что для API 19 и выше панель навигаций(кнопки) при
>   нажатии на экран в пустое место не появляются, только если проводить в
>   область, где они находятся.

Для этого можно сделать так (добавив `GestureDetector` в `OnTouchListener` для `View`, при нажатии на который должен появиться *Navigation bar*):

```
public class ImmersiveActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int INITIAL_HIDE_DELAY = 300;

    private View mDecorView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.immersive_activity);

        final View controlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
        final View contentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);

        mDecorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        mDecorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(
                new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int flags) {
                        boolean visible = (flags & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION) == 0;
                        controlsView.animate()
                                .alpha(visible ? 1 : 0)
                                .translationY(visible ? 0 : controlsView.getHeight());
                    }
                });
        contentView.setClickable(true);
        final GestureDetector clickDetector = new GestureDetector(this,
                new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                        boolean visible = (mDecorView.getSystemUiVisibility()
                                & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION) == 0;
                        if (visible) {
                            hideSystemUI();
                        } else {
                            showSystemUI();
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });
        contentView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                return clickDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
            }
        });

        showSystemUI();
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (hasFocus) {
            delayedHide(INITIAL_HIDE_DELAY);
        } else {
            mHideHandler.removeMessages(0);
        }
    }

    private void hideSystemUI() {
        mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
    }

    private void showSystemUI() {
        mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    }

    private final Handler mHideHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            hideSystemUI();
        }
    };

    private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
        mHideHandler.removeMessages(0);
        mHideHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, delayMillis);
    }
}
```

P.S. для полноэкранного режима можно использовать helper [отсюда](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=NHentai-android-master/app/src/main/java/moe/feng/nhentai/util/FullScreenHelper.java)? а листинк кода №2 взят из примера от Google в ссылках от [этого видео на @YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cBi8fjv90E4)

Comment: Спасибо, то есть для api 18 и ниже мы добавляем доп поток который при нажатии на экран юзеров сразу скрывает кнопки

Comment: @Александр, если не хотите "отвлекать" пользователей, то да. у меня приведен пример с задержкой

Answer (score 1):

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
);
```

Comment: Даже после нажатия на экран, кнопки не появятся. Только через вызов шторки. Очень удобно для FullScreen Games