# Как убрать верхнюю панель?

Tags: android

[image: .]

Как убрать эту панель (где время и т.д.)?

Comment: Посмотри, пожалуйста, [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/689958/227016) и [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2868052/5812238).

Comment: @diraria спасибо!

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2868047/5812238

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно сделать это программно:

```
public class ActivityName extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // убираем заголовок
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Или установив тему с помощью `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

Если вы используете `AppCompatActivity`, то установить тему можно так:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
```

---

<sub>Перевод ответа [@Cristian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2868052/5812238)</sub>